# Disable vagrant plugin execution

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

Is there any way to disable a plugin execution?

For instance, we use `vagrant-librarian-puppet-plugin` and it gets automatically executed when there is a Puppetfile present.
In some cases we want to avoid the execution even if the Puppetfile is present. Is possible to do that adding a configuration in the Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't deactivate plugin; so you need to look into the specific settings of the given plugin.

In the case of https://github.com/voxpupuli/vagrant-librarian-puppet you can't deactivate the plugin but you can tell it to look the Puppetfile into a directory where it will not be

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.librarian_puppet.puppetfile_dir = "directory_with_no_puppet_file"

end
```

Note: I have not tried it myself but looking the [source](https://github.com/voxpupuli/vagrant-librarian-puppet/blob/master/lib/vagrant-librarian-puppet/action/librarian_puppet.rb) it should be okay and will skip librarian provisioning